# JBehave parametrized alias ambiguity

Tags: java, testing, jbehave

Using jBehave, I would like to use a method for both parametrized and non-parametrized steps.
The documentation (http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html) says that I can use an alias like this:

```
@Given("a stock of symbol $symbol and a threshold of $threshold") // standalone
@Alias("a stock of <symbol> and a <threshold>") // examples table
public void aStock(@Named("symbol") String symbol, @Named("threshold") double threshold) {
    // ...
}
```

But it does not allow me to use the exact same sentence. What I would like to do is:

```
@Given("a stock of symbol $symbol and a threshold of $threshold") // standalone
@Alias("a stock of symbol <symbol> and a threshold of <threshold>") // examples table
public void aStock(@Named("symbol") String symbol, @Named("threshold") double threshold) {
    // ...
}
```

But it pops up a warning: "Ambiguous step".

How can I do this?

What would be even better is to write only:

```
@Given("a stock of symbol $symbol and a threshold of $threshold") // standalone
```

And replace the $symbol and $threshold by the examples in the table. Is there a StoryTransformer that could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mauro Talevi replied to me on the jBehave mailing list: http://markmail.org/thread/ef3pfkjoiuuxvic6#query:+page:1+mid:33appvwdkfboyshx+state:results

The solution is to change the configuration like this:

```
new MostUsefulConfiguration()
    .useParameterControls(new ParameterControls().useDelimiterNamedParameters(true));
```

This is probably the configuration bbark is using in its answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
  @Given("a stock of symbol $symbol and a threshold of $threshold")
  public void aStock(@Named("symbol") String symbol, @Named("threshold") double threshold) {
    System.out.printf("Output From Method: symbol: %s, threshold: %s\n", symbol, threshold);
  }
```

Story file:

```
Trader Test


Scenario: test single method
Given a stock of symbol blah and a threshold of 6

Scenario: test again with examples table
Given a stock of symbol <symbol> and a threshold of <threshold>

Examples: 
|symbol|threshold|
| abc  |  2      |
| 123  |  3      |
| asdf |  4      |
| jbe  |  5      |
| have |  6      |
```

Output

```
Scenario: test single method
Output From Method: symbol: blah, threshold: 6.0
Given a stock of symbol blah and a threshold of 6

Scenario: test again with examples table
Examples:
Given a stock of symbol  and a threshold of 

|symbol|threshold|
|abc|2|
|123|3|
|asdf|4|
|jbe|5|
|have|6|

Example: {symbol=abc, threshold=2}
Output From Method: symbol: abc, threshold: 2.0
Given a stock of symbol abc and a threshold of 2

Example: {symbol=123, threshold=3}
Output From Method: symbol: 123, threshold: 3.0
Given a stock of symbol 123 and a threshold of 3

Example: {symbol=asdf, threshold=4}
Output From Method: symbol: asdf, threshold: 4.0
Given a stock of symbol asdf and a threshold of 4

Example: {symbol=jbe, threshold=5}
Output From Method: symbol: jbe, threshold: 5.0
Given a stock of symbol jbe and a threshold of 5

Example: {symbol=have, threshold=6}
Output From Method: symbol: have, threshold: 6.0
Given a stock of symbol have and a threshold of 6
```